# how to determine package name of a gui program/element

Tags: debian

I wanted to write a bugreport for debian. To do this I need to name the package that is affected.

The bug is occuring in the gui version of systemsettings -> mouse&trackpad settings.

How can I determine the package name of such a program?

Comment: Stop the program, capture a `ps` listing, start the program, rerun ps, diff the two. Use dpkg from there.

Comment: I used system monitor before and had trouble finding the newly created process. your tip worked great. gnome-control-c is the new process. Nevermind, thats just copy paste... I used ps -A > test1.txt and ps -A > test2.txt and compared them online. That's why the copy paste process started

Comment: Ok whenever I open up the settings and check with ps -A | grep gnome-control-c I get a hit (closing removes it immediately) so it is the right process. I cannot find a package with that name though. It is gnome-control-center and I found it: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnome-control-center thanks!

Comment: As @JeffSchaller implied, you can easily find which package the file belongs to with `dpkg`: `dpkg -S bin/gnome-control-center`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One general way to find something like this is to capture process listings before and during the program's execution.

1. `ps -A | sort > before.txt`
2. run program here; keep it running
3. `ps -A | sort > during.txt`
4. diff before.txt during.txt

Once you have the pathname of the process, use `dpkg -S /path/to/file` to determine which package owns the file.

Comment: or if you have `dlocate` installed: `dlocate /path/to/file`